# When I refresh the page the Jquery code doesn't work done

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax

I have implemented AJAX code which calls an external page in PHP where a DB is queried and creates a table.
When AJAX calls the page the jQuery code inserts the PHP table in a `<p>` tag which creates a sort of "box" through an animation and resizes the box to HEIGHT according to the PHP table. When it is called the first time it works correctly, when I then close the "box" using the appropriate button and click on it again to review the box, the latter remains blocked with the standard height of the `<p>` tag with which it was defined. How can I fix this and make it work every time I run the jQuery animation without having to refresh the page?

```
<input type="button" value="Close Ripostiglio" class="hidden1" onclick="close1()">
    <p class="par1" id="pa1"> Ripostiglio </p>
    <script>
    function loadDocument(e) {
      var httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
      httpRequest.onreadystatechange = gestisciResponse;
      httpRequest.open("GET","function.php", true);
      httpRequest.send();
      httpRequest.reload();
    }
    function gestisciResponse(e) {
      if (e.target.readyState == 4 && e.target.status == 200) {
        document.getElementById("dinamicZone").innerHTML = e.target.responseText;
      }
    }
                    //OPEN BOX
      $(document).ready(function(){
        //RIPOSTIGLIO
        $(".par1").click(function right(){
          var p = $(".par1");
          var n = $(".hidden1");
          p.animate({left: '300px'}, "slow");
          p.animate({height: '$(#dinamicZone).height()'}, "slow");
          p.animate({width: '350px'}, "slow");
          p.html("<div id='dinamicZone'></div>");
          setTimeout(loadDocument, 2000); //delay the open of table
          n.show();
        });
        function close1(){
        $(".nascosto1").click(function destra(){
          var p = $("#pa1");
          var p = $(".par1");
          var c = $(".hidden1");
          var s = $(".add1");
          p.animate({height: '65px'}, "slow");
          p.animate({width: '150px'}, "slow");
          p.animate({left: '0px'}, "slow");
          s.hide();//TOLGO LA SCRITTA AGGIUNGI
          p.html("Ripostiglio"); //"RIMETTO" FORZATAMENTE LA SCRITTA CANTINETTA VINI
          c.hide();
        });
      }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The dinamicZone object was destroyed in close1(). So when you click on it again, it has no reference to change size to. Reloading the page will reinitialize the page, thus recreating dinamicZone.

Perhaps change the line in close() where you reassign the value of p.HTML. If you comment out that line, the resizing *should* work.

---- ignore below this ----

````
Without it, you're trying to set the height to 65 when it contains an object that is higher, which is probably why it did not work. 

```
 $(".nascosto1").click(function destra(){
          // var p = $("#pa1");  // duplicate
          var p = $(".par1");
          var c = $(".hidden1");
          var s = $(".add1");
          p.html("Ripostiglio"); //"RIMETTO" FORZATAMENTE LA SCRITTA CANTINETTA VINI
          p.animate({height: '65px'}, "slow");
          p.animate({width: '150px'}, "slow");
          p.animate({left: '0px'}, "slow");
          s.hide();//TOLGO LA SCRITTA AGGIUNGI
          c.hide();
        });
```
````

Comment: Tried it, but nothing! Unfortunately when I close via bottene and then reopen it even with your modification it doesn't work. I can't really understand

Comment: So use Chrome inspect mode and see what is the size of object, p, or console.log it. We need to know what is inside.

Comment: the dimensions remain: height = 65px
width: 350px

Comment: Oh. That's the problem. dinamicZone was destroyed by that p.html('Ripostigli') so when you try to read the size again in gestisciResponse(e) nothing will happen.

Comment: I was not sure what you meant by "not work". You mean it did not change size LARGER again. I thought you meant it did not shrink to 65.

Comment: it drops to 65px, but when I click to reopen and do it again it becomes> 65px, then it always stays at 65px

Comment: Read my updated answer. Basically, close1() destroyed dinamicZone, so if you click again, it does not know how to interpret the height as that object no longer exists. Maybe comment out the p.html(... line and see what happens.

Comment: I tried to comment on p.html (...) but nothing, the problem remains. I created that close1 () function so that the "box" was returned to its original position and size. Commenting on p.html (), the box shrinks and returns to its place but the table remains visible.

Comment: Kasey do you have some ideas??